# Contributions of Chevalley to Category Theory

Tags: category-theory, math-history

I am aware that Chevalley has contributed substantially to category theory. His name is often mentioned in category theory books. In accounts of the history of modern algebraic geometry, and accounts of the Bourbaki group, he is often mentioned as part of the group advocating for categorical methods.

Can someone point me to a reference where Chevalley's contributions to category theory are detailed?

Of course I would also appreciate anyone who is familiar with Chevalley's work to simply rattle off a long list of examples.

Comment: The only thing that immediately comes to mind is the Beck–Chevalley condition. You might trawl through the list of matches on [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/search?query=chevalley).